# Python making multiple columns in a dataframe into a single column

Tags: python, excel

I have a large dataframe with multiple columns (>1000) in Python and i wish to combine them into a single column so that i can transfer it into excel in the format that i want it to be.

Eg.

```
1   100   500   900
2   200   600   1000
3   300   700   1100
4   400   800   1200

into

1  100
2  200
3  300
4  400
5  500
6  600
7  700
8  800
9  900
10 1000
11 1100
12 1200
```

Any suggestions/solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `pandas`, try using `Series` with `flatten`:

```
print(pd.Series(df.values.flatten()))
```

**Edit:**

Or if you want to keep the order:

```
print(pd.concat([df[i] for i in df.columns]).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Comment: i tried this method but it seems like it rearranges the sequence of my values when in a single column

Comment: @jaclynx Check my **Edited:** section, please accept and upvote if it works :)